# Error while unserialization of model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

on my production system occurs an error while unserializing an user object within queue execution:

```
[2016-12-20 21:10:01] production.ERROR: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException: No query results for model [App\User]. in /var/www/virtual/bob/bobnet/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php:210
    Stack trace:
    #0 /var/www/virtual/bob/bobnet/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/SerializesAndRestoresModelIdentifiers.php(45): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->findOrFail(137)
```

If I run

```
\App\User::findOrFail(137)
```

the correct user could is found without an error. Until a few weeks everything worked fine. Just as the unserialization on my dev system.
Has anyone an idea what's going wrong?

Notification:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class GuideNotification extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    // Once the data has been set to a public property, it will automatically be available in the view
    private $template;
    public $user;
    public $tour;
    public $pivot;
    public $sender;
    public $date;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($template = 'emails.status_update', \App\User $user, \App\Tour $tour, $pivot, \App\User $sender = null)
    {
        $this->template = $template;
        $this->user     = $user;
        $this->tour     = $tour;
        $this->date     = new Carbon($tour->start);
        $this->pivot    = $pivot;
        if ($sender) {
            $this->sender = $sender->fullName();
        }

    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this
            ->to($this->user->email)
            ->cc(config('bob.bcc_mail'), 'BoB')
            ->subject($this->generateSubject())
            ->view($this->template);
    }

    protected function generateSubject()
    {
        switch ($this->template) {
            case 'emails.request':
                return 'Guide Anfrage ' . $this->tour->name . ' am ' . $this->date->format('d.m.Y') . ' um ' . $this->date->format('H:i') . ' Uhr (ID ' . $this->tour->id . ')';
                break;
            case 'emails.confirmation':
                return 'Guide Bestätigung ' . $this->tour->name . ' am ' . $this->date->format('d.m.Y') . ' um ' . $this->date->format('H:i') . ' Uhr (ID ' . $this->tour->id . ')';
                break;
            case 'emails.change':
                return 'Guide Änderung ' . $this->tour->name . ' am ' . $this->date->format('d.m.Y') . ' um ' . $this->date->format('H:i') . ' Uhr (ID ' . $this->tour->id . ')';
                break;
            case 'emails.freesale':
                return 'Guide Bestätigung "geschnappte" ' . $this->tour->name . ' am ' . $this->date->format('d.m.Y') . ' um ' . $this->date->format('H:i') . ' Uhr (ID ' . $this->tour->id . ')';
                break;
            default:
                return 'Guide Statusupdate ' . $this->tour->name . ' am ' . $this->date->format('d.m.Y') . ' um ' . $this->date->format('H:i') . ' Uhr (ID ' . $this->tour->id . ')';
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: from where `GuideNotification` class is invoked? Did you check if the right user object is passed to the construct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short:

Due to some environment variables and execution context the queue was worked with a different php version which resulted in this error. After forcing the correct php version everything works fine.